# Use UIViews into UIViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, storyboard

I have 2 UIViews into a UIView. I'm using this because I want to show an object and if is photo type or text type, I'm using a view or other. Using this I can do it with only one segue, and not 2 going to 2 different viewControllers.

[image]

It's a good practise or I have to create 2 viewControllers and make 2 segues?

I'm using hidden properties to hide or show views.

`self.photoView.hidden = YES;
self.textView.hidden = NO;`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good practice but you should use a [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)
Make sure that you show only one at the time and handle hide and show updates.
In your situation you have one view and 2 subviews. This is totally fine.
But if you get more complex View structure maybe it's better to make 2 separate viewControllers or one ViewController but with 2 custom Views.

Comment: Yes i'm using self.textView.hidden = YES for example to hide or show views. 2 o 3 views will be the max number of subviews...

Comment: You can also have a look on ChildViewControllers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html
you can put your subview into childViewControllers in future, but I would start with simple thing first